# While reading the value of Radio button, value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of a selected radio button. I tried the below way, but I am getting the value as `undefined`.

```js
var nameSelected;
$('.m-radio-inline input').on("change", function() {
  nameSelected = $('input[name="abc"]:checked').val();
});
alert(nameSelected);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-radio-inline">
  <label class="m-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Ash" checked> 
    Ash
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <label class="m-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Win"> 
    Win
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

It should give Ash/Win

Comment: You need to work with `nameSelected` *within* the event handler. Currently, when you `alert()` the value the event hasn't happened, so `nameSelected` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's alerting before `nameSelected` has a value - place the `alert` inside the `change` handler:

```js
var nameSelected;
$('.m-radio-inline input').on("change", function() {
  nameSelected = $('input[name="abc"]:checked').val();
  alert(nameSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-radio-inline">
  <label class="m-radio">
 <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Ash" checked>Ash
 <span></span>
  </label>
  <label class="m-radio">
       <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Win">Win
       <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert(nameSelected);` when this line is executing the event has not been fired.

Comment: This just seems to describe the issue and does not answer the problem. How can the OP fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to alert on some action nameSelected is undefined first time and the value set on change function so it alerts undefined

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->



var nameSelected;
$('.m-radio-inline input').on("change", function() {
  nameSelected = $('input[name="abc"]:checked').val();
  alert(nameSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-radio-inline">
  <label class="m-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Ash" checked>Ash<span></span>
 </label>
  <label class="m-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="abc"  value="Win">Win<span></span>
 </label>
</div>
```